# Generate dataset traffic in mininet

Tags: dataset, pcap, sdn, mininet, ryu

I created a topology using mininet and connected it to Ryu controller. I also downloaded a dataset in .pcap format which is real network traffic for a period of time. Now I want to generate this traffic into mininet network. How can I do that? Any idea please.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Based upon your reading of documentation, do you have an idea of what that would look like? You may also want to reformat your question according to recommendations (i.e. edit button below question) in [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

TCPReplay, D-ITG, and scapy are tools for traffic replay. However, I am not familiar with using mininet so I suggest you check the documentation to see how these tools can be integrated.